# How to copy child object in array

Tags: modifiers, parent

I have parent object and some array modifiers on it. Also my parent object has some childs, but they are not copied by array modifier, despite they have a parent-child relationship. I need child objects to be copied like parent objects, maintaining their position relative to the parent.  How can I do this?

(Window frame as a child object and walls as a parent)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Modifiers alter the vertices of the modified mesh. AFAIK they are not inherited by children.  Will need to re-think this. Can join hierarchy into one mesh, or choose a method other than array (directly)  to distribute.

Comment: But boolean modifiers that modifies mesh ARE inherited. I want the childrens objects to be copied as well as parent object on the same positions

Comment: do you have any reason not to join the 2 objects? You could also keep them separated and array the frame as well...

Comment: Joining 2 objects will cause destructive workflow because after joining  window frame with the walls it immediately dissappears because of difference boolean modifier, so I have to apply them before joining two objects, so I fall into destructive workflow

Comment: To clarify. If a child object is used in  a boolean modifier  to cut a window (or whatever) into mesh that is then arrayed, that there are windows on each array instance is not due to inheritance.  Agree with moonboots, can also array frame.  Consider distributing collection instances.  A single vertex mesh can be arrayed  dupliverts

Comment: or use a boolean union modifier to add frame child. This will alter the mesh of the original making the frame arrayed.

Answer (score 2):

**Boolean Union Modifier**

Modifiers alter the vertices of the modified mesh.

[image]

Hide the child frame object and "join" it to the wall mesh using a boolean union operator before the array modifier(s).

Example image small cube "Cube.001" child of arrayed big cube "Cube".

Re materials

[Join objects (boolean) with different materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91781/join-objects-boolean-with-different-materials)

Note: this is not inheritance, (the object need not be a child) the modifier alters the mesh of the original.

Comment: Note : If your window frame has a different material than your walls, the boolean modifier will overwrite it unless you add the window frame material to the list of materials of your parent object (no need to actually apply it to a face though)

Comment: For sure.  Will need to make sure the "unit" renders as desired.  A QA re that came up recently will look for link.  Personally would still lean to making a collection instance and "arraying it" with duplis. Could contain armatures et al and would preserve per object materials.

Comment: @Gorgious I have noticed a point cloud object type is available (non save-able demo last I looked)  in later versions of blender.

Comment: It seems part of the basic structure of Blender atm that you can't modify Collection Instances, which is maybe reasonable? - but a pity.

Comment: Hopefully the new depsgraph will help bring the possibility forward. Have noticed using `self` in drivers and printing confirms `self` is the evaluated object.